# complex convex functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I call a function f defined and valued on a domain A in the plane convex if it maps convex areas to convex areas. Some obvious example of convex functions. If f is also a bijection, what can we say more about it? I guessed that if f is a diffeomorphism(C2) of the complex plane then it is linear, say az+b. This is related to a quadratic form of its differentials fxx,fyy,fxy. However, I cannot strictly confirm this. Is there any classical analysis addressing with this question? If any, please help show the sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that *A bijection from the plane to itself that sends convex sets into convex sets is an affine transformation.*

Indeed, it must not be hard to see that such bijection sends lines to lines (into what would it send a half-plane given that it is convex and has a convex complement??) and then one applies the fundamental theorem of affine geometry.

Comment: So this quesion is indeed trivial. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: nice! it seems it's a rule: when dealing with some problem about convex objects, never forget to start by the linear or affine ones...

Comment: Well, I think that there are little details to be checked, but if you assume the map is a homeomorphism, then its easy.